# Difference between id and name attributes in HTML form

Tags: html, attributes

What is the difference between the id and name attributes? They both seem to serve the same purpose of providing an identifier.

I would like to know (specifically with regards to HTML forms) whether or not using both is necessary or encouraged for any reasons. If using both together, should they use the same? like id="animal" and name="animal" when naming the attributes

Comment: Read the basic [docs](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/what-is-the-difference-between-the-id-and-name-attributes.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The difference between `name` and `id`:**

**id** is used to identify the HTML element in the page. id is expected to be unique within the page.

**name** corresponds to the form element and identifies what is posted back to the server.

*using both is necessary or encouraged for any reasons?* it's not necessary, for form element just name is enough but if you want to do some `CSS` or `JS` operations, doing it on the element with id is much more easier.

*If using both together, should they use the same?* no, they aren't related to each other.

Answer (score 0):

ID is normally used for javascript and css, whereas name will be mostly used for pass the value (from url) using a backend language such as php.

Answer (score 0):

From [this article](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/what-is-the-difference-between-the-id-and-name-attributes.html):

> The `id` attribute is a unique identifier of the HTML element. Each id
> attribute must be unique. It can be used as an anchor reference in
> URL. It isn’t associated with the data within the element.

> The `name` attribute defines the name of the element. It is used in the
> HTTP request that is sent to the server as a variable name by the
> browser. This attribute is associated with the data within the
> element.

For example:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Radio Buttons</h1>
    <form action="/form/submit" method="post">
      <p>Select your gender:</p>
      <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
      <label for="male">Male</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
      <label for="female">Female</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
      <label for="other">Other</label>
      <br>
      <p>Select your age:</p>
      <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="30">
      <label for="age1">0 - 25</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="age2" name="age" value="60">
      <label for="age2">25 - 50</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="age3" name="age" value="100">
      <label for="age3">50 - 80</label><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```